# podman kube play --replace --service-container=true， what service-container isused for？

Tags: podman

I use podman and systemd to run pods, and I found in the `podman-kube@.service` file, `exec_start = podman kube play --replace --service-container=true`, what does `--service-container=true` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The docs of podman kube play seem to be outdated.
The release notes of podman version 4.4.0 mention the switch, though:

```
When the --service-container option is set for the podman kube play command, the default log-driver to is now set to passthrough (#16592).
```

source: https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/RELEASE_NOTES.md#changes-6